# How to verify with JavaScript if canvas is supported?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The following HTML allows to inform users in case `canvas` element is not supported by browser:

```
<canvas id="canvas">
  Your browser doesn't support canvas element
</canvas>
```

How could I get the same information with JavaScript (for ex., to disable some button)?

Comment: `var supportsCanvas = "getContext" in document.createElement('canvas')`

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a canvas and check for a method:

```
var supportsCanvas = !!document.createElement("canvas").getContext;
```